# Update remote forked repository without get it cloned locally from Github

Tags: git, github

I forked [vinta/awesome-python](https://github.com/vinta/awesome-python).

I didn't clone it to the local.

A week later, the upstream `vinta/awesome-python` has updated multiple commits.

I intent to synchronize my forked repository with it.

So I firstly delete my forked `awesome-python` from my Github account and re-fork from the upstream repository.

Is there a smart way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Synchronizing a repo with upstream could require a merge and merge can only be done locally. Hence there is no way to update a fork without cloning it locally.